# How do I implement a BFS in ns2 for a wired scenario?

Tags: ns2

How do I implement a BFS in ns2 for a wired scenario?

Is there a way to find the neighbor of a node?

I want to calculate the aggregate demand of a node based on its child nodes, where demand of leaf nodes is defined.